# Difference between the functions "im2uint8" (in MATLAB) and "bytescale" (in Python)

Tags: python, matlab, dicom

I want to convert a DICOM image from int16 to uint8. I have done it in Python using `Z_axis = bytescale(img)`, but this gives different results than using `im2uint8` in MATLAB. In MATLAB, The minimum and maximum values of a DICOM image after converting to uint8 using `im2uint8` are (124, 136), respectively. But these values in Python after converting using `bytescale` are (0, 255).

Python code:

```
for person in range(0, len(dirs1)):
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, dirs1[person])):
    Pathnew = os.path.join(directory, dirs1[person])
    os.makedirs(Pathnew)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, dirs1[person])):
        dcmfiles = [_ for _ in files if _.endswith('.dcm')]
        for dcmfile in dcmfiles:
            dcm_image = pydicom.read_file(os.path.join(root, dcmfile))
            img = dcm_image.pixel_array
            Z_axis = bytescale(img)  
            minVal = Z_axis.min()
            maxVal = Z_axis.max()
```

Matlab code:

```
for j = 1 : length(Files2)
    img = dicomread([galleryPath Files2(j).name]);
    Z_axis = im2uint8(img);
    minVal = min(min(Z_axis));
    maxVal = max(max(Z_axis));
```

The images look equal when displayed, but the numeric values are not. So, are the `bytescale` and `im2uint8` functions equal or not? If not, I want results like `im2uint8` in Python. What kind of function should I choose (especially for DICOM images)?

For example, in MATLAB after reading a DICOM file:

```
img = dicomread([galleryPath Files2(j).name]);
img = [ -1024,   -1024,   16;
        -1024,       8,   11;
           17,       5,    8];
```

But in Python, the same image after reading is:

```
dcm_image = pydicom.read_file(os.path.join(root, dcmfile))
img = dcm_image.pixel_array
img = array([[ -1024,    -1024,   27],
             [ -1024,       27,   26],
             [    24,       26,   23]])
```

I don't know why they are different in MATLAB and Python. After applying `im2uint8` in MATLAB, the output is:

```
Z_axis = im2uint8(img)
Z_axis =
 3×3 uint8 matrix
   124    124   128
   124    128   128
   128    128   128
```

And after applying `bytescale` in Python, the output is:

```
bytescale(img)
Z_axis = 
    array([[0,    0,   83],
           [0,   83,   83],
           [83,  83,   83]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, regarding the issue with reading the data, I would suggest using [`dcmread`](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/ref_guide.html#pydicom.filereader.dcmread) in Python, as that gave me the same exact data as [`dicomread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html) in MATLAB.

Secondly, in MATLAB when [`im2uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2uint8.html) converts `int16` values it will scale them assuming minimum and maximum values for the data equal to -32768 and 32767, respectively (i.e. the minimum and maximum values representable by an `int16`). For [`bytescale`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.bytescale.html) to behave equivalently, I believe you need to set the `cmin` and `cmax` arguments accordingly (since they will otherwise default to `data.min()` and `data.max()`, respectively). This should replicate the results of `im2uint8` in Python:

```
Z_axis = bytescale(img.astype(float), cmin=-32768, cmax=32767)
```

Note: conversion of the data to float first is necessary to account for an apparent bug in `bytescale` that doesn't handle the integer arithmetic properly (found courtesy of [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo)).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: In the above example, How to convert int16 to double in Python (like Matlab)? I used, image_v = eng.double(img) but it has had an error: (TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray)

Comment: @eli: Perhaps `image_v = img.astype(double)`?

Comment: NameError: name 'double' is not defined

Comment: @eli: Sorry, I think `float64` is the correct type name.

Comment: Yes and I use it as " image_v= np.float64(img)".

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's different

`bytescale` convert matrix to uint8 normalizing all values by the the highest and the lowest (highest 255 and lowest 0)

```
img = array([[ 91.06794177,   3.39058326,  84.4221549 ],
                 [ 73.88003259,  80.91433048,   4.88878881],
                 [ 51.53875334,  34.45808177,  27.5873488 ]])

bytescale(img)

array([[255,   0, 236],
       [205, 225,   4],
       [140,  90,  70]], dtype=uint8)
```

In Matlab `im2uint8` it's useful to convert double images to uint8. Double images has range 0 to 1.
To do the same in Matlab fist you need to convert image in range of value 0-1 (double) normalizing the data, then apply im2uint8.

```
I = [ 91.06794177,   3.39058326,  84.4221549;
    73.88003259,  80.91433048,   4.88878881;
    51.53875334,  34.45808177,  27.5873488];

Inorm = (I - min(I(:))) ./ ( max(I(:)) - min(I(:)) );

I2 = im2uint8(Inorm);
```

Then you obtain the same image:

```
I2 =

  3×3 uint8 matrix

   255     0   236
   205   225     4
   140    90    70
```

Comment: I want to use "im2uint8" in python. what kind of function should I choose? (especially for dicom images)

Comment: Can you comment a sample of a image values like I did in my comment.

Comment: How can I send you a dicom file?

Comment: No, only a 3x3 matrix with values, to see the datatype

Comment: after applying `im2uint8` in your img matrix my result in Matlab is `img8 =

  3×3 uint8 matrix

     0     0   255
     0   255   255
   255   255   255`

Comment: In your code, it is used as  Z-axis = im2uint8(double(img)) that the output image is not acceptable; but my image matrix is an int16 (dicom), that's mean: Z-axis = im2uint8(int16(img)) or Z-axis = im2uint8(dicom image).

Comment: I don't know the reason why in my code the output images in Python and Matlab are the same, but their min and max values are different!

Comment: `img = np.array([[ -1024,    -1024,  27],
         [ -1024,  27,   26],
         [ 24,  26,  23]])` 

`Z_axis = bytescale(img.astype(float), cmin=-32768, cmax=32767) Z_axis=array([[124, 124, 128],
       [124, 128, 128],
       [128, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8)`

Comment: Yes, Now, They are the same. Thank you for replying.

Comment: If that answer is correct it would be good to mark it as such :) @eli