# How to fix import error of 'bytescale' from 'scipy.misc' in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, scipy

Already, I have used the `bytescale` in my python 3.6. code, that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725553/difference-between-the-functions-im2uint8-in-matlab-and-bytescale-in-pyth) is its explanation.
After installation of `Scipy` based on `Anaconda`, it is imported without any problem, but  an import error occurred after (`from scipy.misc import bytescale`)

So,

```
import scipy.io as sio  # without any error

from scipy.misc import bytescale # with an error.
```

Error:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'bytescale' from 'scipy.misc'
```

Also,

```
Version of Python is 3.7, Windows 10

scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0    anaconda

pillow                    6.1.0            py37hdc69c19_0
```

Then, I found that "`bytescale` is deprecated! `bytescale` is deprecated in `SciPy 1.0.0,` and will be removed in `1.2.0`". 
Now, I need to a function that works such as `bytescale` in Python 3.7.

Is there any function such as "bytescale" in Python 3.7.?

Comment: Try ```pip install PIL``` or ```pip3 install Pillow```. Also, have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298665/cannot-import-scipy-misc-imread)?

Comment: @Pedro Henrique: I saw the link and I installed `Pillow` but the problem not resolved.  Also for `pip install PIL`: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none).`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL.`

Comment: `scipy.misc.bytescale` was deprecated in SciPy 1.0 and removed from SciPy 1.2.

Comment: What do you need `bytescale` for?

Comment: @hpaulj: I used `bytescale` instead of `im2uint8` (Matlab); Ex: `Output = bytescale(img.astype(float), cmin=-32768, cmax=32767)`

Comment: @gnovice: Is there any functions such as `bytescale` for python 3.7.?